# Word for someone who likes to define things simply

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for someone who likes to define things, often to a detrimental effect by over simplifying them - due to either lack of intellect/laziness etc.

I’m thinking of Trump like figures who rather than explain something/someone is complicated , use a single word to describe it.

Example, After being explained why his computer was not working by the IT technician for the 6th time and Jim still unable to understand, Jim called him a nerd. The IT technician replied “you don’t know anything, perhaps you should stop calling people names and being such a …”

Or.. After the meeting with the leading human rights lawyers of the day, Trump unable to understand the intricacies of the debate labelled them “interfering liberals”. A journalist noted this was the first of a series of names Trump used throughout the conversation in order to deflect from his lack of detail, an action increasingly being called … by some in the media.

I hope that makes sense and isn’t too ironic

Comment: It seems to me that those people, Jim and Trump, do not "define" anything, and that instead, they are   crudely dismissive, the first much more so than the last.

Answer (score 2):

[**reductionist**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reductionist) maybe.
Lexico defines it thus:

*often derogatory*

> A person who analyses and describes a complex phenomenon in terms of
> its simple or fundamental constituents.
>  *‘a crude reductionist’*

It's an older word than I imagined: from 1861, according to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=reductionist).

Comment: Calling someone a nerd does not amount to an analysis of someone's personality in terms of its fundamental constituents; it is giving an overall characterization of that personality, which, in the example provided by the OP, is probably not even true. In my opinion there is no case for calling someone like that a reductionist. It is not different for the second example used in the query.

Comment: The first two sentences of the question suggest 'reductionist' but the examples are, as you say, 'dismissive'. +1

Comment: I see, the examples can just be disregarded as a mere error in what is an illustration, and not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Ignorant - lacking knowledge or awareness in general; uneducated or unsophisticated.

Person doesnt understand the subject so generalizes into terms they know and and can associate. often derogatory to put the person down to elevate the self